# Social Sharing plugin for Ionic 4 for web browser

Tags: ionic4, socialshare, socialsharing-plugin

do you know of Social Sharing plugins that works with Ionic 4 when run on the browser? Most are for mobile so I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

Social Share via web will be constrained by the available API and by the way you implement meta tags handling in your application. Here is web API based implementation that yo can use or learn from:

https://github.com/peterpeterparker/web-social-share